# Is it possible to have chocolate chunks in ice cream that aren't waxy?

Tags: chocolate, dessert, ice-cream

My wife loves mint / chocolate chip ice cream. It hasn't been my favorite because of how waxy the cocoa butter in the chocolate becomes when it is cold.

Is there a type of chocolate that won't become waxy when it is frozen?

Alternatively is there a good intensely chocolatey, chunky, ingredient that can be mixed into ice cream? And in particular, mint ice cream.

I'm wondering about solid ingredients not syrups.

Comment: Oreo cookie crumbs? *shrug*

Comment: possible duplicate of [What type of chocolate is in chocolate chip ice cream](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12868/what-type-of-chocolate-is-in-chocolate-chip-ice-cream)

Comment: If you make your own mint ice cream, you could add good quality dark chocolate chunks from the fridge each time, rather than freeze them.

Comment: Bits of chocolate fudge? Bits of brownies?

Answer (score 2):

I use dark chocolate chips (Whole Foods brand, vegan) when I make my own ice cream, and have not encountered any waxy texture. I can vouch for that but you can probably experiment with your favorite chocolate chips.

Somewhat OT but making mint ice cream isn't too hard if you have an ice cream maker, just follow the instructions for vanilla but use mint extract instead. Then add the chips when the ice cream is about 5 minutes away from being finished in the ice cream maker.

Comment: Mostly-agreed, but why use mint extract?  Fresh mint is infinitely plentiful (ask anyone you know who gardens), and steeping it in your dairy overnight gives all the mint flavor and none of the chemicalness of the extract.

Comment: Go for it @StevenStadnicki! I've also made ice cream with fresh mint and fresh vanilla beans, but sometimes it's just easier to pour in some extract.

Answer (score 2):

You can use baking chocolate or chocolate chips, the key is to melt it! After you melt it, pour it on a baking sheet and freeze it, chop it up then keep frozen until ready to use. If you want melty, or fudgy chips/chunks, add some heavy cream to the melted chocolate until just barely pour-able. If it is too thick to stir, add more cream. Go slowly, don't add too much or you'll have chocolate milk.The grittiness you feel when you freeze chocolate comes from the stabilizers they use when making the chocolate, melting it solves the issue. Add it to the ice cream in the last few minutes of churning!

Comment: This is interesting. It isn't stabilizers, you are detempering the cocoa butter. Normally it's a bad thing but I can see how the softer texture could work in ice cream. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

I made some mint chocolate chunk ice cream and I chopped up a dark chocolate dove bar and it was dreamier than ever expected! 
And I certainly agree with waiting until the last 5 minutes from when the ice cream is done to add the chocolate